# How to auto click a toggle button?

Tags: android

I have a toggle button on action bar for switching camera and I want to auto click on toggle button that is place on action bar when ever I start video call .

Comment: You want to [toggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#toggle()) the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you a solution for this:

```
private MenuItem toggleButton;

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    toogleButton = menu.findItem(R.id.your_toggle_button_id);
    return true;
}

private void startVideoCall() {
// Your code to start video here
...
// Auto set toggle button on.
toggleButton.setChecked(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the activity starts, call this `toggleButton.setChecked(true);`  and prepare a listener for the toggle button like this:

```
toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
          if(isChecked){
            //start video call
          }
      }});
```

Comment: its not working :/